# Does the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x-2\alpha\sqrt{x}}\,{\rm d}x$ have a closed form expression?

Tags: integration

I would like to calculate this integral:

$$I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x-2\alpha\sqrt{x}}\,{\rm d}x.$$

I set $t=\sqrt{x}$ and then I found : $\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{2t}$. So

$$I=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty 2te^{-t^2-2\alpha t}\,{\rm d}t=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty 2e^{-\alpha^2}te^{-(t+\alpha)^2}\,{\rm d}t.$$

I let $t+\alpha=z$ and I get:

$$I=\displaystyle2e^{-\alpha^2}\int_\alpha^\infty (z-\alpha)e^{-z^2}\,{\rm d}z.$$

What to do now.

Comment: Split the integral in two parts: $\int ze^{-z^2} dz - \alpha\int e^{-z^2}dz$. The first integral can be solved using substitution and the second do not have an elementary closed form (but can be expressed using the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Then make use of the complementary [error function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.2)
$$
\text{erfc}(x):=\frac2{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,{\rm d}t
$$
 to end up with

> $$
> \int_0^\infty e^{-x-2\alpha\sqrt{x}}\,{\rm d}x=1-e^{\alpha^2} \sqrt{\pi } \:\alpha  \:\text{erfc}(\alpha).
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x + 2 \alpha \sqrt{x} = y \implies dx = \left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x} + \alpha}\right)dy$$

Check that we can write the above as $$dx = \left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{y + \alpha^2}}\right)dy$$ (since $x \geq 0$)

Hence $$I = \int_0^\infty e^{-y}\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{y + \alpha^2}}\right)dy = \Gamma(1) - \alpha \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}dy}{\sqrt{y + \alpha^2}}$$

Now $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-y}dy}{\sqrt{y + \alpha^2}} = \int_\alpha^\infty \frac{e^{-(t^2-\alpha^2)}(2t dt)}{t} = e^{\alpha^2}\sqrt{\pi} \int_\alpha^\infty \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-t^2} dt = e^{\alpha^2}\sqrt{\pi} ~\text{erfc}(\alpha) $$ 
where $y + \alpha^2 = t^2$

Hence $$I = 1 - \alpha e^{\alpha^2}\sqrt{\pi} ~\text{erfc}(\alpha)$$